# How to make Snackbar MatchParent In Tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar

I am trying to make the `Snakbar` to `MatchParent` in TAB. What I have done is:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(coordinatorLayout, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

    View view = snackbar.getView();
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)      view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);

    snackbar.show();
```

It increases the width a little big not to the MatchParent

Answer (score 2):

For anybody still looking for an answer:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(coordinatorLayout, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

View view = snackbar.getView();
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)      view.getLayoutParams();+
params.gravity = Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;
view.setLayoutParams(params);

snackbar.show();
```

The 'FILL_HORIZONTAL' did the trick for me.